# Finding the branch points of $\log(z^2-1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

This example is presented in the following paper (http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.305/Notes/n00Branch_Points_B_Cuts.pdf, example 2.2, page 11). The author uses the identity $\log(z^2-1)=\log(z+1)+\log(z-1)$ and then proceeds to study the branch points of the two logarithms. However, aren't all these functions multivalued? How does he know that $\log(z+1)$ is continuous on the circle centered at $1$ while $\log(z-1)$ is not? I just cannot make sense of that argument. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The branch points of $f_1(z)=\log(z-1)$ are $A_1=\{1,\infty\}$.

The branch points of $f_2(z)=\log(z+1)$ are $A_2=\{-1,\infty\}$.

The branch points of $f(z)=f_1(z)+f_2(z)=\log(z^2-1)$ are $A_1\cup A_2 = \{1,-1,\infty\}$.

A branch cut for $f_1(z)$ must connect the two points of $A_1$ and a branch cut of $f_2(z)$ must connect the two points of $A_2$.

To select branch cuts for $f(z)$, we can take two branch cuts, one from each of these points to the point at $\infty$.

The function $f_1(z)$ has a branch point at $z=1$, so any circle surrounding this point will necessarily run into a branch cut.  The function $f_2(z)$ does not have $z=1$ a branch point, so for this function, surrounding the point $z=1$ by a circle poses not difficulty for circles of radius less than 2 (the distance between the points $\{1,-1\}$, as long as we don't run the branch cut through this circle.

**UPDATE**

**The point at $\infty$ is a branch point of $f(z)= f_1+f_2$ and thus the segment $[-1,1]$ is not a valid branch cut.**

Thanks to @Maxim for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: $[-1, 1]$ is not a valid choice of a branch cut for $f$ ($f = f_1 + f_2$ as a multivalued function, not $f_1 f_2$), because $\infty$ is a branch point.

Comment: I agree that I've made a mistake writing $f_1 \cdot f_2$ rather than $f_1 + f_2$, I'll correct it.  I believe, though (could be wrong), that if the angles are properly defined, say by taking a branch cut on $[-1,1]$, the point at $\infty$ is no longer a branch point.

Comment: Either $\infty$ is a branch point of $f$, as your answer (correctly) says, or it's not. A choice of branch cuts can not change the location of branch points. You won't be able to construct a branch of $f$ analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus [-1, 1]$.

Comment: Okay, correct.  Either $\infty$ is or is not a branch point of $f(z)$.  I claim it is not.  There are many choices for branch cuts.  A cut may simply connect $1$ and $-1$ or a cut may go through the point at $\infty$ while connecting $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Please see the figure added to the answer.  Very similar.  Consider $f_1 - f_2$.

Comment: Hildebrand (p. 507) also has the example $f(z)=\log[z(1-z)]$ with exactly two branch points $z=0$ and $z=1$.  This is almost identical to the situation here.

Comment: Let $\varphi_1$ be the angle between the line joining $z$ to 1 and the $x$-axis, and $-\pi <\varphi_1<\pi$ and $\varphi_2$ be the angle between the line joining $z$ to $-1$ and the $x-$axis and $0<\varphi_2<2\pi$.  Then $\arg f(z) = \phi_1 + \phi_2$  is well defined other than the segment $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Does your reference consider the point $\infty$ at all, in any of the examples? If it were saying that one can define an analytic branch of $\ln(z (1 - z))$ on $\mathbb C \setminus [0, 1]$, that would be plain wrong. You can see why $f_1 + f_2$ and $f_1 - f_2$ are different by considering how the angles add up or by writing $f(z) = 2 \ln z + \ln(1 - 1/z^2)$, where now only one term has a branch point at $\infty$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying that!  Yes, cases $f_1 + f_2$ and $f_1 - f_2$ are intrinsically different, as you say.  Also, carefully looking at the text again, he limits the discussion to "finite branch points" so that not mentioning $\infty$ does not imply that $\infty$ is not a branch point.